# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDate] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jparepository

I have a springboot project with mysql and jpa and in there I have a model/domain class

```
class MyClass {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String data1;
    private Integer data2;
}
```

and I also have repository interface that extends JpaRepository where I want to add a custom query to pick rows with latest date by name - the code is as follows:

```
interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select m.name, max(date) from MyClass m group by m.name")
    List<String> selectLatest();
}
```

When the call of that query is executed I get the error message as in the title

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDate] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.lang.String]
```

I have found similar questions but each was more specific to a class and more complex than mine, I think it's the java.util.LocalDate that's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select two columns which is not a string. Your message returns an `Object[]`:

```
interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select m.name, max(date) from MyClass m group by m.name")
    List<Object[]> selectLatest();
}
```

Where the index zero contains the name and the index 1 contains the Date.

But for me a better solution is to create an Object with two attributes and select this:

```
public class MyLatestClass {
   private String name;
   private LocalDate date;
   
   public MyLatestClass(String name, LocalDate date){
     this.name=name;
     this.date=date;
   }
   //getter 
   ....
}

interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select new MyLatestClass(name, max(date)) from MyClass m group by m.name")
    List<MyLatestClass> selectLatest();
}
```

Comment: do you think you could explain a bit why you think the second option is better than using Object[]? - it would help me understand your point of view a bit better, thanks

Comment: is it because if I use Object[] I have to write code that has to be written to convert returned data and if I use a predefined class the code is cleaner as a result?

Comment: It is better maintainable if you can access the values per getter and setter as with index. Think about changing the order or adding new attributes